# SQL Server, Random Auto sticking to the bottom

Tags: sql, sql-server

What's going on with this..

Primary Key, Not Null, Auto

One row just sticks to the bottom.

[image: SQL Server Image]

Not a big deal, just wondering for future reference and to satisfy my curiosity.

Thanks.

Comment: What is this program you're using? SSMS? Some random datagridview in another application of some sort? There is no inherent order in queries unless you specify an order by statement, so it's free to get the data in whatever fashion it thinks it most efficient. Is this part of a larger query by any chance, looking at some other data, which could affect the order?

Comment: Makes sense, I guess I just assumed as it usually runs chronologically. Bizzare how one single row doesn't conform though, but every other row does. Using SSMS. Thanks for the response - upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SGBDs, tables are un-ordered sets of records, this is from the very Set Theory and Relational Algebra where SGBDs are built upon, and means that, although there's a physical order for records, this should not matter and SGBDs are not obliged to keep any consistency unless `ORDER BY` clause is used.

Comment: I accept this as how it works, I was just curious as to the behind the scenes workings of how everything is in order naturally apart from the single row - Accepted regardless.